# How to get the active Row of the WPF DataGrid inside the TemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I have a WPF Datagrid with three columns. The first two columns DataGridComboBox Columns. The third column is the Template column with ContentControl inside. I want to use this Datagrid as Data entry form for an advanced search. The first column will be binded with the list of properties about a document in the databse (like DocumentName, OwnerName, DateCreated etc). The second column will be a list of Operators (<,<=,!=). These operators will be dynamically changed based on the property selected from the combobox in the 
cell[0]. This is handled in the SelectionChanged event of the first comboBox.

Inside the content control(In cell[2]),I need to load a DataTempalte(each contains diffetent UI controls like autocompleteBox,DatePicker,etc) defined in the window's Resources based on the property selected in the comboBox in the first colum. I have added a custom template selector for this purpose. But I am unable to access the DataGrid ComboxBox and its content of the first cell inside the DataTempalte selector code.

Please note that I didn't want to bind existing data to the datagrid. The datagrid will be used as data entry form. So I always want to retain the values selected in the previous rows in edit mode only.

Please refer the sample code from my UI and code behind:

```
public class DocumentSearchProperty
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is the class which I set as a itemsource for my Datasource.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="Auto" Name="documentPropertyGrid"
                            ItemsSource="{}"
                            SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" 
                            CanUserResizeRows="False" FrozenColumnCount="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RowHeaderWidth="0"
                            AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="columnProperty" ItemsSource="{}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" 
                                                 Header="Property" Width="170"/>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="columnOperator" ItemsSource="{}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=value}" Header="Operator" Width="170" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="PropertyValue" Header="Value" Width="100">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="CntControl">
                                                <ContentControl.Content>1</ContentControl.Content>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

The below code is used to handle the selection changed event of the first comboBox. Inside this selection changed event I can get the ComboBox in the cell[1]. But I cannot get the ContentControl in cell[2]. Can anybody suggest a better way to achiveve this?

```
DataGridRow row = this.documentPropertyGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(this.documentPropertyGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
            ComboBox ele = this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as ComboBox;
            ContentControl contentControl = this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row) as ContentControl;
```

I have made following changes for getting the third column of the grid as content presenter:

```
ContentPresenter contentPresenter = this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row) as ContentPresenter;
```

After the above change I can now assign a datatemplate dynamically to the contentPresenter as follows in the SelectionChanged event of the comboxBox Column(in the first column).

```
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "DocumentName":
                        dt = this.FindResource("AutoCompleteBoxTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                        break;
                    case "DateCreated":
                    case "DateModified":
                    case "DateAccessed":
                        dt = this.FindResource("DatePickerTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                        break;
                    default:
                        dt = this.FindResource("AutoCompleteBoxTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                        break;
                }
                contentPresenter.ContentTemplate  = dt;
```

But now in the second column the Operator values which I have set are replaced with the latest operator in all the rows. For e-g If the property selected in the first combo box is TemplateName there will be a list of two operators (Equal,NotEqual). But when the DateCreated is selected in the first comboBox then the operator column in the second row should display (<,<=,>,>=). But since I am assigning these operators by using the name of the comboxColumn(columnOperator), the operators in the first row also updated with operators for DateCreated. How to restore the values in previous rows?

Comment: What is the type of `this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)` when it is not shown as a content control?

Comment: I have given a default value 1 inside the content Control (which is inside the datatemplate of the datagrid'd template column). You see the following declartion in the Xaml given above:<ContentControl.Content>1</ContentControl.Content>. The value of 1 is dispalyed in the cell[2] when the page is loaded. So I hope it is an empty content control with value 1(?).

Comment: What I meant was when you put a breakpoint on the line `this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)` what value do you see in the `Watch` for `this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)` ? Null? string? UIElement?

Comment: The value for "this.documentPropertyGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)" is returned as ContentPresenter.

Comment: Interesting! Well I am not sure why `ContentPresenter` is returned from the call but its the core / heart of the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl`. `DataGridCell` itself is a `ContentControl` so another `ContentControl` (that you have put) inside it is **assumed** to be a `ContentPresenter`. Well if it doesnt harm you then you can extract all content based properties `Content`, `ContentTemplate`, `ContentTemplateSelector`, `ContentStringFormat`, `ContentSource` from `ContentPresenter` itself!... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx

Comment: I have edited my origial post. I have done exactly what you have suggested now.It sloves the problem of loading different datatemplates in the column 3. But I have another issue is loading the comboBox values(different source in diffrent rows in column2). please review the edited post.